# Confusion Matrix error : Mismatched Datatypes between Actual and Predicted Values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, keras, confusion-matrix

[image]

Original Dataset is as shown above. CO(ppm) is the dependent variable.

```
model = Sequential()
#First Hidden Layer
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='random_normal', input_dim=19))
#Second  Hidden Layer
model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='random_normal'))
#model.add(Dropout(0.3))
#Output Layer
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer='random_normal'))
```

For a binary classification problem shown above, I am trying to obtain the **confusion matrix**.
I have arrays resulting from y_pred and y_test and the datatypes are mismatched because the y_pred outputs a **range of values from 0 to 1**(sigmoid activation function) and the y_test has an array consisting of **only 0s and 1s**.

[image]
[image]

I would greatly appreciate it if someone can help me figure a method to plot the confusion matrix for this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing any predicted class is greater or equal to 0.5 and given that the final activation maps any value between 0 and 1 non-inclusive you could do the following:

```
y_pred = np.where(y_pred >= 0.5, 1, 0)
```

Any value greater and equal to 0.5 will be mapped to 1, otherwise 0. After this you can obtain the confusion matrix using sklearn's confusion_matrix method:

```
sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
```

Example:

```
y_true = np.array([1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0])

y_pred = np.array([0.8, 0.1, 0.4, 0.6, 0.9, 0.69, 0.46, 0.21])
y_pred = np.where(y_pred >= 0.5, 1, 0)

sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
```

Output:

```
array([[4, 0],
       [0, 4]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried the above and it worked for y_pred but not for the confusion matrix. y_pred is an array but y_test is not. Getting an error for mismatched data types. Is there any way to convert the y_test column to an array ? Thanks.